# CMYK Mode after generating a PDF of images in DOMPDF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf, cmyk

I am working on HTML to PDF generation, i am using laravel with DOMPDF library, I have 3 different images, i have that image through css and html, its working fine, but after when we downloading the file and opening into Photoshop its show RGB mode

[image]

I want it to show cmyk Mode.

[image]

This is the output file of my pdf

[image: HTML Format]

```
My PDF download code after rendering the html
$customPaper = array(0,0,4500,2950);
$pdf->setOptions(['dpi'=>300]);
$pdf->loadHTML($html)->setPaper($customPaper)->setWarnings(false)->save($filename.'.pdf');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: Are you saying the original image is in CMYK and you want it to remain that way? Or that you want a PDF that uses the CMYK color space? Though Dompdf has some CMYK support I believe it converts everything to RBG during render.

Comment: Yes, i want that PDF in cmyk format by default, Bust Dompdf not giving me anything to set the color of entire pdf as default in cmyk

Comment: Any updates on this? I need this as well?